# File Upload - Add to existing Input

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have the following file input box that allows for multiple upload:

```
<input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
```

My users pick their files and they appear in a list. But say after picking their files a user wishes to add more files without overwriting the existing files chosen. Is it possible to add on to the list of existing files or would I need a new file input element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should make new input element (perhaps by insert a new input element in onclick event handler).
This is [reference link from Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileList) about FileList object.